# Is there a GUI in xorg for changing the video driver?

Tags: gnome, xorg

I was under the impression there was a GUI app for changing the Xorg video driver. If so, where is it? I don't see it in 10.04.

Comment: There's almost certainly a better question to be asked lurking under this one.  Why do you want to change the Xorg video driver? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean a GUI for changing display-related properties, then you can find that at `System->Preferences->Monitors`.

If you are referring to a GUI tool for editing `xorg.conf`, I am not aware of one - you're better off editing the file directly (details [here](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xorg.conf.5.html)).

Comment: `System->Preferences->Monitors` Will only work when it's using xorg drivers that it supports xrandr, etc. I also agree though that there isn't (to my knowledge) a GUI for modifying the xorg configuration file. Though that sounds like it might be a helpful tool.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to switch between the proprietary and Free driver for your video card (e.g. if you have an ATI or NVidia card), try jockey.

On the default Ubuntu desktop this is in:
System - Administration - Hardware Drivers

You can enable and disable hardware drivers there.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for `dpkg-reconfigure`. It's terminal-based GUI for reconfiguring software. You should be able to change your xorg driver settings with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`.

Comment: +1, although not a proper GUI, it's a nice interface to configure your xorg via a few keystrokes. Also you can use it in the virtual terminal if you break things up :)

Comment: This won't do anything interesting on a modern Ubuntu system (from 9.10 onwards, I think).  The packages no longer ship a default X configuration - it's all autodetected.